# For loop condition how to print values until index 5

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to use for loop condition that print values until index 5. what is the best way to apply this condition.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Hi', 'Ali', 'jak','kind', 'happy', 'Ali','smile', 'hak','cute']})
```

Comment: `df_1.iloc[0:5, :]` or `for x in df_1.iloc[0:5, 0]: print(x)`

Comment: just `df_1.head()` ?

Comment: this should work `df_1[:5]`

Comment: [`head()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) vs. [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop. Simply `df_1[:5]` will work. But if you absolutely need to use a loop, use this:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(df_1.iloc[i])
```

Comment: Hi, it does not work:  KeyError: 0     ----> 2     print(df_1[i])

Comment: made a typo. it's fixed now.